# Spoof OS for VPN?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, spoofing

My company uses Juniper VPN for remote access. Unfortunately, they have not upgraded Juniper to allow remote access for Windows 10.

Juniper uses Java and executables to verify.

Is there a way to spoof my OS (beyond user agent) to windows 8 or 7?

Comment: Have you tried to change the compatibility settings to older versions of Windows?

Comment: @rcorreia - tried that, but no go. Windows 10 is actively excluded, so I'm looking for a way to bypass.

Comment: I never did that, but I suggest try to mess with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion. Maybe Juniper client uses some of these entries.